# Print username and password used in spring security authentication

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have been having some trouble logging in when typing the credentials in the login page. For some reason, I am typing a wrong password even though I have checked the correct one in the database. So I thought of printing in the console the password that I type. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote up an approach at http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=2029 - this is a followup to this earlier post: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=2003

As I mention in the post, since this will print cleartext passwords on the console, be sure to remove this as soon as you determine and fix what's misconfigured.

Comment: I placed this class under src/groovy. Where would you suggest me to call additionalAuthenticationChecks from? The domain class? The controller? The LoginController maybe?

Comment: You don't call it, Spring Security does. As long as your class is registered as the AuthenticationProvider, it will print the info for every login attempt.

Comment: I got it! Cleartext: 'admin' from DB: 'admin' hashed '$2a$10$EqDexlHvWUL1JnaAasLRbe7JfoUKNVdLLJOd30GoK1Q.v45.wdboi' Valid: false