# How to get plain password or decrypt password from Spring Security in Grails?

Tags: spring, security, grails, spring-security

I am using **Spring Security Plugin** in Grails application. When saving the password it is in encrypted format in the database. I want to send it plain password. How to get it?

Another Android application uses my API. From my API, I needs to send particular User's password.

Comment: You don't want to sent the plain password (nor would it be possible). If you have an application and are able to send a plian password I would mark that as a security risk. Allow for a password reset instead.

Comment: Deinum...Thanks for your reply...Another application used my API...For that application, further usage needs to send password to that application...

Comment: @Visme listen to M. Deinum. Just don't store plain text passwords and don't send them around. If you need to reset a password generate a new, one time, password, send it to the user and let the user to pick a new password of their choice. It's better for the users that way and even for you because should your user database get compromised the attacker would get hashed and salted passwords not the real passwords.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading the passwords from db: when passwords are saved to the database they are [hashed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) not [encrypted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption), and [the process involved in hashing is not reversible](http://learncryptography.com/why-are-hashes-irreversible/), so the simple answer is: **No you cant.**

---

You can use encryption when saving the passwords to the database ( so that you can decrypt them when you come to the unusual scenarios like in your case) but it is not a good idea, [that is why hashing functions are preferred to encryption algorithm for saving passwords](http://www.darkreading.com/safely-storing-user-passwords-hashing-vs-encrypting/a/d-id/1269374).

---

But if you really require this and know how to handle the risks you can intercept the calls to `user.save()`, specifically intercept the `beforeInsert()` and `beforeUpdate()` methods that is where the password gets encoded.

So your user's `beforeInsert()` and `beforeUpdate()` methods will look like this:

```
beforeInsert(){

    ...
    yourApiService.sendPassword(password)
    ...
    password = securityService.encodePassword(password)
    ...

}


beforeUpdate(){

    ...
    if(isDirty('password')){

        yourApiService.sendPassword(password)
        ...
        password = securityService.encodePassword(password)

    }
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion for you is to use spring [security rest plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-rest) if you are exposing some your APIs to some external apps. To get started with spring security rest, have a look at [greach2014 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Va2OlHQdonI&list=PLXcHRe1w86EdmLLNs1chNt5QdEJb_skTj&index=10).

If you still insist on using plain text password, you are not the only one to request this but with different intention. The only logic behind storing plain text passwords is to debug login issues in spring security. It is not meant to be used in production application. Someone else posted [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468570/print-username-and-password-used-in-spring-security-authentication) to debug the login issues and Burt Beckwith (the maintainer of spring security plugin) wrote [this blog](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=2029). In this blog he has explained how to store plain text passwords.